# Difference between bulk.ToString() and bulk.tojson()

Tags: mongodb

Is there any difference between [bulk.ToString()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.toString/) and [bulk.tojson()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.tojson/) in the mongodb?

Comment: bulk.ToString() is like JSON.stringify(bulk.tojson())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any difference between them. Both returns the the same type - `"String"`.

If you see under the covers, bulk.toString() actually calls bulk.tojson().

```
> bulk.toString
function () {
      return this.tojson();
    }
> typeof(bulk.toString())
string
> typeof(bulk.tojson())
string
> bulk.tojson() === bulk.toString()
true
```